# fire fox does not display some html border

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

in [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/riateche/eQ8rz/3/) I create HTML table. When I save the code in html file and open it with firefox, there is no problem. When I save it as jsp and run this with apach tomcat, and open it with firefox, some of the row borders and colum borders will not displayed (no problem in chrom or internet Explorer).

Any Idea what could be the problem?

p.s: I have Firefox version 12.0
thank you

Comment: If it doesn't display correctly as jsp, you are likely passing data that needs to be escaped. Make sure you escape any escape chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, two things:

1. TR are just structure elements, they cannot have borders (but TD, TH and TABLE can have some) ... and TR can have background-color by the way
2. the left border of a td might "override" the right border of the left one. read a little bit into http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/css/properties/table/bcollapse.htm and you'll find a cool solution

Comment: @ Christian Lavie: you mean to use "separated"? but it has a terrible look